# Compute Polynomial

Tags: c

Polynomial is a0x^0 + a1x^1 +a2x^2 + a3x^3 + ... + anx^n
Can you help me please?

```
 int degreeOfPolynomial;
double[] coefficients;

public Polynomial() {

}

public Polynomial(int degree) {

    for(int loopingVariable = 0; loopingVariable<=getDegree(); loopingVariable++) {
        this.coefficients[loopingVariable] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to construct the string `"x^2 + x + 1"`? If so, what attempt have you made?

Comment: Do the binary digits correspond to the powers of x? I.e. would 1000 correspond to x³ + 0 + 0 + 0?

Comment: @ Syn Yeah correct

Comment: Have you learned `for` loops? How to pick out individual characters from a string? Testing whether a character is equal to a literal value? How to append strings?

Comment: you are constantly changing your question so that the answers you got do not even apply anymore. Well the basic principle still does, but still...

Comment: @jhdm Please restore the question, approve one of the answers, and then pose a new question, and do say something more about what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

in the reverse order:

```
int poly = 13;
int power = 0;
int mask = 1;
boolean nothing = true;
while (mask <= poly) {
    if ((mask & poly) != 0) {
        if (nothing) {
            nothing = false;
        } else {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
        if (power == 0) {
            System.out.print("1");
        } else if (power == 1) {
            System.out.print("x");
        } else {
            System.out.print("x^" + power);
        }
    }
    ++power;
    mask <<= 1;
}
System.out.println();
```

In right order:

```
int poly = 13;
int power = 0;
int mask = 1;
boolean nothing = true;
while (mask <= poly) {
    mask <<= 1;
    ++power;
}
while (power > 0) {
    --power;
    mask >>= 1;
    if ((mask & poly) != 0) {
        if (nothing) {
            nothing = false;
        } else {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
        if (power == 0) {
            System.out.print("1");
        } else if (power == 1) {
            System.out.print("x");
        } else {
            System.out.print("x^" + power);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: The OP didn't tell us if 0 was a possible input value.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson if the input value is zero, it will print nothing

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I tested this and it works according to the first form of your question, where there were no coefficients of x.

In order to apply it to your question as it currently stands you would have to go through both the string and the coefficients array and correlate the 2.

```
String binaryNumber = Integer.toBinaryString(number);
String polynomial = "";
for(int i=0;i<binaryNumber.length();i++){
   if(binaryNumber.charAt(i)==('1')){   
      if(polynomial.length()>0){
         // We already have some value in the polynomial so we add a + before the new values
         polynomial += "+";
         }
    // We append the new x together with its appropriate exponent based on some index arithmetics
    polynomial += "x^"+((binaryNumber.length()-1)-i);
    }
}

System.out.println(polynomial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 13;
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(number); // prints 1101

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < binaryString.length(); index++) {
            int pow = binaryString.length() - 1 - index; // the pow

            if (binaryString.charAt(index) == '1') {   // skip when the bit is 0
                String toInsert;
                if (pow == 0) {  
                    toInsert = "1"; // when pow is 0, append 1
                } else if (pow == 1) {  
                    toInsert = "x"; // when pow is 1, append x
                } else {
                    toInsert = "x^" + pow; // else append x^pow
                }
                stringBuilder.append(toInsert + "+");
            }
        }

        String result = stringBuilder.toString();
        if (result.endsWith("+")) {
            result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1); // remove last "+"
        }
        System.out.println(result); // x^3 + x^2 + 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` has much better bit manipulation functionality that most of the others numerical values.

```
public static String asPoly(long n) {
    return asPoly(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
}

public static String asPoly(BigInteger b) {
    // Using BigInteger because it has a bitLength.
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int p = b.bitLength(); p >= 0; p--) {
        if (b.testBit(p)) {
            switch (p) {
                default:
                    parts.add("x^" + p);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    parts.add("x");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    parts.add("1");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return String.join(" + ",parts);
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    int number = 15;
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));
    System.out.println(asPoly(number));
}
```